# Issues with headers on proxy

Tags: java, proxy

I'm experiencing some frustrating issues with the headers on a proxy I'm doing using sockets.

This is what I receive when I connect to www.google.es (for example):

```
GET http://www.google.es/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.es
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: PREF=ID=62a609089cbce13d:U=20c30fc6df717cbe:FF=0:LD=es:TM=1378210903:LM=1384897041:S=wX0-kDwF5KqLESKr; NID=67=wbjT3HqfQNz0JSuq11Rpmu4C_fY69quKSF_rfe_VAdK-oiKejeFaTwJi7jHcYyEbrHms8by5lkrEHIlXGZJGKYgDTma4kQF8JVqZddinnI75T5v-EJ90we-OUc93HegBxX0gbhWKF1-_EmkptGY; OGPC=4061029-1:; OGP=-4061029:; __qca=P0-1591457945-1384728978104; __gads=ID=fd5470c0fda87be6:T=1384738414:S=ALNI_MaS2YtYfdr0-_d4mn78YuI6py6CWQ; centralnotice_bucket=1-4.2
Connection: keep-alive
```

Then to establish the connection I'm doing this:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
connection = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0");
connection.connect();
```

Please note that I'm setting User-Agent header with exactly the same value I'm getting from the browser.
But when I try to connect to www.google.es I receive this error:
**302 Moved
The document has moved here.**

If I comment out the header "setRequestProperty":

```
//connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0");
```

Then I receive the web page, but it looks different than the original one (without proxy).
What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write a correct HTTP proxy using the `HttpURLConnection` class. You have to deal in TCP sockets and process the CONNECT command. After that, just copy bytes in both directions.

Comment: Hi EJP, would be possible for you share a little piece of code to see how I need to execute this CONNECT command? I don't know how to do what you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

Call `HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true)`.

It seems that the server behaves differently based on User-Agent. The web site redirects your client to another page (by sending 302 to your client) when User-Agent is "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0", but currently your client does not follow the redirect.